# Is there a way to use `outer` to two vectors when the FUN will produce more than one value

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a function like this

```
myfun <- function(x, y){
  c(x, y, x+y, x*y)
}
```

I want to use it in the function `outer` like this

```
vmyfun <- Vectorize(myfun)

outer(1:10, 2:5,vmyfun)
```

and I would like the result is a list with 4 matrix

```
  [[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    2    2
 [3,]    3    3    3    3
 [4,]    4    4    4    4
 [5,]    5    5    5    5
 [6,]    6    6    6    6
 [7,]    7    7    7    7
 [8,]    8    8    8    8
 [9,]    9    9    9    9
[10,]   10   10   10   10

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    2    3    4    5
 [3,]    2    3    4    5
 [4,]    2    3    4    5
 [5,]    2    3    4    5
 [6,]    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    2    3    4    5
 [8,]    2    3    4    5
 [9,]    2    3    4    5
[10,]    2    3    4    5

[[3]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    3    4    5    6
 [2,]    4    5    6    7
 [3,]    5    6    7    8
 [4,]    6    7    8    9
 [5,]    7    8    9   10
 [6,]    8    9   10   11
 [7,]    9   10   11   12
 [8,]   10   11   12   13
 [9,]   11   12   13   14
[10,]   12   13   14   15

[[4]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    4    6    8   10
 [3,]    6    9   12   15
 [4,]    8   12   16   20
 [5,]   10   15   20   25
 [6,]   12   18   24   30
 [7,]   14   21   28   35
 [8,]   16   24   32   40
 [9,]   18   27   36   45
[10,]   20   30   40   50
```

is there a way to implement this? Thank you guys.

**update** :
I have made a bad example for this question. What I really want is much more complicated than the example result I provided. 
I do not want to change the function `myfun`. This is a new example.It is a function to get the sum of a mat for different threshold.

```
myfun2 <- function(x, y){
  mat <- matrix(data = rexp(x, rate = y), nrow = 10, ncol = 20)

  sapply(seq(from = 0, to = max(mat), length.out = 100), function(x){
    mat[mat < x] <- 0
    sum(mat)})
}


> myfun2(10,15)
  [1] 10.023527 10.023527 10.023527 10.023527 10.023527 10.023527 10.023527 10.023527  9.893362
 [10]  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362
 [19]  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362
 [28]  9.893362  9.893362  9.893362  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354
 [37]  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354  9.353354  8.563003  8.563003
 [46]  8.563003  8.563003  8.563003  8.563003  7.673577  7.673577  7.673577  6.729326  6.729326
 [55]  6.729326  6.729326  6.729326  6.729326  6.729326  6.729326  6.729326  6.729326  5.590193
 [64]  5.590193  5.590193  5.590193  4.385858  4.385858  4.385858  3.113081  1.828594  1.828594
 [73]  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594
 [82]  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594
 [91]  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594  1.828594
[100]  1.828594
```

this function will create a vector of length 100 for a give `x` and `y`.
I want to uses it like this.

```
vmyfun2 <- Vectorize(myfun2)

outer(1:15, 1:10,vmyfun2)
```

and the result should be a list of 100 matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`outer` does not support this, but we can achieve this via `lapply`:

```
## function list `funlist`
funlist <- list(function(x, y) x, function(x, y) y, "+", "*")
## use `lapply`
lapply(funlist, FUN = function (fun) outer(1:10,2:5,fun))
```

---

```
[[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    2    2
 [3,]    3    3    3    3
 [4,]    4    4    4    4
 [5,]    5    5    5    5
 [6,]    6    6    6    6
 [7,]    7    7    7    7
 [8,]    8    8    8    8
 [9,]    9    9    9    9
[10,]   10   10   10   10

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    2    3    4    5
 [3,]    2    3    4    5
 [4,]    2    3    4    5
 [5,]    2    3    4    5
 [6,]    2    3    4    5
 [7,]    2    3    4    5
 [8,]    2    3    4    5
 [9,]    2    3    4    5
[10,]    2    3    4    5

[[3]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    3    4    5    6
 [2,]    4    5    6    7
 [3,]    5    6    7    8
 [4,]    6    7    8    9
 [5,]    7    8    9   10
 [6,]    8    9   10   11
 [7,]    9   10   11   12
 [8,]   10   11   12   13
 [9,]   11   12   13   14
[10,]   12   13   14   15

[[4]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    2    3    4    5
 [2,]    4    6    8   10
 [3,]    6    9   12   15
 [4,]    8   12   16   20
 [5,]   10   15   20   25
 [6,]   12   18   24   30
 [7,]   14   21   28   35
 [8,]   16   24   32   40
 [9,]   18   27   36   45
[10,]   20   30   40   50
```

---

**Follow up**

My knowledge with R is fairly limited. Thanks to @thelatemail's comment, I think I learn using `Map` from today:

```
Map(outer, list(1:10), list(2:5), funlist)
```

Comment: Beat me to it - you can also specify it via `Map(outer, list(1:10), list(2:5), funlist)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I do not change my function to a function list. I   have made a update.